# Is a question too broad if its title is?

Tags: discussion

People [closed my question as too broad](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74149/how-are-focus-groups-done?noredirect=1#comment115347_74149) titled ***How are “focus groups” done?*** but in the question I go on to ask 2 very simple, specific questions about focus groups:

1. **Who are these people, how are they gathered?**
2. **Do people have jobs to act as focus group attendees or are there agents in charge of going out and finding completely random people of specific or distributed demographic groups?**

@JohnGB claimed that these questions would take an entire book to answer. How then, John, were they answered in 2 paragraphs. An answer wasn't just summarized. It perfectly and objectively answered both questions successfully.

"How are they done?" was just a word choice that summed up the question, which seems to be what a title should generally be.

**I feel that it is wrong for people to close this question, because it was actually very specific, very simple, and had a good accepted answer which answered both questions perfectly:**

> There are companies that run focus groups. I've been selected to
>   attend a few of them, as has my spouse. Usually an ad is placed
>   somewhere and people are vetted in a phone interview or online survey.
>   The vetting process chooses people in the target demographic for the
>   group. (such as "people caring for a family member with cancer" or
>   "women who have remodeled their kitchen in the past 3 years" or "men
>   between the ages of 30-45 who are thinking about purchasing a van in
>   the next 12-18 months"). Sometimes the groups are rather broad,
>   sometimes extremely specific. They are usually paid for their time,
>   and the payment is quite generous.
>
> The group is brought together and shown various things and is asked
>   questions about them. Products, options and features, advertising,
>   etc.
>
> A focus group is generally geared toward product/feature development
>   or marketing and advertising (I once sat in on a focus group for
>   Celebrex ads, for example).
>
> That is different from a user test, where people fitting the different
>   user personas are brought in to try different interfaces or tasks.
>   User testing is ideally done in a lab of some sort, with sophisticated
>   eye tracking and/or video recording (and screen capture) equipment. Of
>   course, user testing can also take place under much more modest
>   circumstances, and often does since many companies don't want to spend
>   the resources to conduct expensive and detailed user testing.

Comment: The question wasn't closed. It was simply put On Hold temporarily to give you a chance to make some amends. John is correct that it's a broad enough topic for there to be [whole books about it](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=sr_nr_n_8?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A266239%2Ck%3Afocus+group&keywords=focus+group&ie=UTF8&qid=1424961343&rnid=1642204031) so it might just be the question title itself that can be narrowed. On Hold questions are easily changed to Open ones. Just a quick edit will add it automatically to the 'reopen' queue for people to judge for themselves.

Comment: My intention of putting it on hold, was to give you a chance to edit it.  Yes, the content is more focused, but the title sets up the expectation.  If titles don't match the question, then that itself is a problem.  I think it has potential to be a good question with just a few tweaks to it, and hope that you do that.

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks for taking the effort to make your case here.

I think the question, as currently written, has the following problems:

1. The title is too broad.  Titles do matter because they are weighted heavily in search, so an overly broad title has the consequence of drawing a lot of false hits and wasting time for folks in the future.  Particularly when it can be rephrased easily, e.g. "selection process for focus groups"
2. Even if #1 is fixed, your question showed no attempt to do any background research on a question that is very well covered by articles, books, blogs, websites, tools, and companies.  SE is not a great venue for "lazy, broad questions" because you are essentially asking others to do a simple google search for you.

I think your question can be fixed if you go address the 2 issues above.  People want to help here, and will spend valuable time doing so.  But to solicit this time, a question has to be reasonably phrased and show a reasonable amount of effort and thoughtfulness on the asker's part before one demands time from the community.  It's more than a fair quid pro quo given the $0 price.